# Matplotlib x axis date tick frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I have a simple dataframe that looks something like this (Year is the datetime index column):

```
Year         A          B
2018-01-01  1.049400    1.034076    
2017-01-01  1.056371    1.032066    
2016-01-01  1.063413    1.030055
```

I graph the data using:

`df['A'].plot()`

`df['B'].plot()`

And get this graph with date tick labels every 5 years.

[image]

How can I make the year ticks appear every 2 (or any other number) of years?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md

x = range(2000, 2018, 1)
year = [f'{str(y)}-01-01' for y in x]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': year,
                   'A': np.sin(x),
                   'B': np.cos(x)})

df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format = '%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
df.set_index('Year', inplace = True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (6, 4))

df['A'].plot()
df['B'].plot()

step = 2
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator(step, month = 1, day = 1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y'))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You can manage the number of ticks with `md.YearLocator()`, in particular with the `step` value. I report the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html) for this method.
Pay attention to the type of the df index: in order to make the code work properly, the dataframe index column has to be a `datetime.date`, so I used the `.dt.date` method to convert from `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` (because I built the dataframe in that way) to `datetime.date`. This depends on the type of data you have.
Some examples:

**step = 2**

[image]

**step = 4**

[image]

**step = 10**

[image]

Comment: I tried the code, but it doesn't quite work. I think something's up with my date index. When I set a=30, b=48 and step=1 using your code, I get the same graph as I posted. My starting year is 2000 and the last year is 2018, so a=30 is 1970+30=2000, and 1970+48=2018 I assume. When I set step=2, the ticks appear every 10 years instead of 5.

Comment: I updated my answer. Pay attention to the dataframe index column type: it has to be a `datetime.date` type.